# Extra data in Skipper stream

Tags: node.js, sails.js, skipper, streams2

Currently writing code to make a skipper gridfs adapter. When you call upload, files are passed in the callback and I would like to add an extra field to the files that contain the metadata of a gridfs store and the ID of a gridfs store.

I'm looking through the Upstream code in skipper and see something called stream.extra. I'm guessing it's for passing extra data, how would I go about using this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for working on this!  You can add extra metadata to your stream by putting it on the `__newFile` object in the receiver's `_write` method.  For example, in the bundled s3Receiver, you can see this on [line 61](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper/blob/master/examples/s3Receiver/index.js#L61):

```
__newFile.extra.fsName = fsName;
```

which is adding the newly generated filename as metadata on the uploaded file object.  In your  controller's `upload` callback, you can retrieve the extra data from the returned file objects:

```
req.file('myFile').upload(function (err, files) {
    var newFileName = files[0].extra.fsName;
});
```